# Как расставить запятые? [1]

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Это очень долго(,) и не факт, что сработает.

Какие здесь грамматические основы?

Answer (score 1):

Про грамматические основы сейчас учёный люд придёт рассказывать, а запятая, вестимо, нужна ввиду наличия присутствия присоединительной конструкции.

Ср.: *Это очень долго, причём не факт, что сработает.*

Про основы предположу:

1) это долго,

2) не факт,

3) сработает.

Answer (score 1):

Это очень долго, и не факт, что (это) сработает.

**Запятая в сложном предложении перед союзом И**, сочинительная связь. Предложения 2 и 3 составляют сложноподчиненное предложение, причем придаточное  предложение 3 неполное.

Грамматические основы: (1) это долго, (2) не факт, (3) сработает.

Comment: То есть *не факт* — все-таки предикативная основа?

Comment: Думаю, что это односоставное предложение с отрицательным значением:  нет уверенности, нельзя считать фактом.